# Android Architecture Components: ViewModel keeps getting re-initialised

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I have an activity that uses the [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) architecture component:

```
class RandomIdViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var currentId : MutableLiveData<String?> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        currentId.value = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    }
}
```

And then in my Activity I have this in the **onCreate()** method:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RandomIdViewModel::class.java)
viewModel.currentId.observe(this, idObserver)
```

Every time I rotate my phone the Id changes. So I am fairly confused as to why init is being called when I set the viewModel object.

**EDIT**

I have been looking at the [saving state UI guidelines](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states) and it definitely appears that the ViewModel should maintain it's data throughout simple configuration changes:

> ViewModel is ideal for storing and managing UI-related data while the user is actively using the application. It allows quick access to UI data and helps you avoid refetching data from network or disk across rotation, window resizing, and other commonly occurring configuration changes. ...
>
> ViewModel is ideal for storing and managing UI-related data while the user is actively using the application. It allows quick access to UI data and helps you avoid refetching data from network or disk across rotation, window resizing, and other commonly occurring configuration changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that having a global variable in the activity that is stores a reference to the ViewModel as a once off causes the issue. All the examples seem to use the VM in a local variable, which doesn't work for me (I don't want my observers to be declared inline as it starts making the code quite messy<sup>1</sup>). The local variable seems to get a new instance every time a config change occurs. However if I create a method:

```
private fun viewModel() = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RandomIdViewModel::class.java)
```

and I call this whenever I need the VM. I think this is a bug that will most likely be resolved in the future.

<sup>1</sup>As a side note I also need to point out that I also had to remove my observers when the activity was not using them. This was another reason why I couldn't just inline the definition of the observers as they happen in different lifecycle events:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    viewModel().currentId.observe(this, idObserver)
}

override fun onPause() {
    viewModel().currentId.removeObserver(idObserver)
    super.onPause()
}
```